# Make regsvr32 ignore a DLL dependency

Tags: installation, dependencies, dll

I'm trying to get some software to function that we don't have the installer to (and the company is unable to supply).

A custom DLL needs registering, which we have but it relies on another DLL - a driver for a Basler industrial camera (`PYLONBASE_MD_VC80.dll`). Eventually found that online. Now a whole Pandora's Box of DLLs is needed:

```
XERCES-C_MD_VC80_V2_7.DLL
GCBASE_MD_VC80_V2_0.DLL
GENAPI_MD_VC80_V2_0.DLL
LOG_MD_VC80_V2_0.DLL
LOG4CPP_MD_VC80_V2_0.DLL
```

These are proving hard to find.

Is there any way to get the software to ignore the whole `PYLONBASE_MD_VC80.dll` dependency as it will never need it (no Basler cameras are being used)?

*All this is being found through Dependency Walker.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write your own stub version of `pylonbase_md_vc80.dll` that exports empty functions that match the names imported by the DLL you need to load.  Dependency Walker should show you the names of the functions that DLL imports from `pylonbase_md_vc80.dll`.  You may have to put dummy parameters in the functions if the imported names are decorated with `@NUMBER` suffixes.

Alternatively, you may be able to find a tool that can mark `pylonbase_md_vc80.dll` as a [delay load DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx) in the DLL that you possess.  Then, it should load and run without ever needing `pylonbase_md_vc80.dll`, as long as no call is made to a function in the latter.  I don't know of any such tool though.